# How to add new maven module into existing maven project

Tags: maven-2

I mean is there a possibility to run some maven command to add new module to existing project , or manually create folder and needed changes to pom.xmls ?

Comment: I've only ever done it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working with Eclipse (m2eclipse) you can add a maven-module via Eclipse (NetBeans and IntelliJ should work the same way) otherwise you have to do that manually...editing the pom and create the folder and put stuff into the new module.

Comment: For Eclipse:rightclick parent project: new file -> other -> maven module

Answer (score 17):

If you are using archetypes, `mvn archetype:generate` will create subproject's POM and structure, and will also set it as a module of the current project.

Comment: This is a better answer. The OP asked how to do it in maven and not via a specific IDE.

Comment: This will add the module to the aggregator POM ?  ...Or it'll just give the new, generated project's POM a parent declaration (for inheritance) ?

Comment: can you provide an example command that will add a submodule? just running mvn archetype:generate will generate a huge list of possible archetypes to pick one from..

Answer (score 3):

To add to @khmarbaise's answer,
If you are using Idea, right click on your project's name on (Project view perspective) and New > Module. Select maven and follow the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new module in eclipse then do follow below steps:

1. Right click on root project. and select maven -> New maven module project
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdPcP.png

but parent project must be pom project like add pom in your pom.xml of root project if you face any error.